# Question about the orbits of electrons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, quantum-spin, pauli-exclusion-principle

A friend recently asked me the question, "If electrons have a negative charge and the nuclei of atoms have a positive charge, why don't electrons simply collapse into the nucleus and sit on it?".

I tried to direct him to things such as the Pauli Exclusion Principle or Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle, calling upon him to see an electron as a space of probability densities rather than a particle, but ultimately neither did he feel satisfied nor could I give a satisfactory answer (considering especially my limited knowledge of atomic physics).

Could you give an answer for me and for him, in some detail, that explains both intuitively and with some depth why this is?

Comment: In a nutshell, as atoms exist, it  is an experimental fact, and  the theories evolved so as to explain it.  Quantum mechanical solutions fit perfectly the spectra of atoms, the postulates ( http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html ) chosen  so as to do so.  So the mathematics of quantum mechanics explain "why", but the system was chosen so that it would fulfill the experimental observations.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend's intuition was sound; a negative charge orbiting a positive charge would spiral closer and closer and eventually crash into it.

This was the main motivation for the Bohr model of the atom. One of the main postulates of the Bohr model was that an electron orbiting a nucleus can only take on discrete orbit radii around the nucleus, which it could transition to and from by absorbing/emitting photons. According to the Bohr model, the reason that the electron doesn't crash into the nucleus is because there is a lowest, closest definite orbit called the ground state.